# How to describe a collection of thing as a vocabulary property in ALPS descriptor?

Tags: api, descriptor

To describe REST APIs in an application-centric matter, I am trying out the [ALPS](http://www.alps.io/) descriptor and its toolings.

Say I have an object "Artwork", an artwork has the following properties: headline, artform, authors, etc.

How should I describe the property "authors"? In OpenAPI spec it is easy, simply say "type: Array", then specify reference under "items". What is the equivalent way of describe a collection in ALPS?

I am using YAML format to describe the API.

My current descriptors looks like this:

```
descriptors:
# vocabulary properties
- id: "identifier"
  type: "semantic"
  text: "Unique identifier within Alpha Org. This is not the serial number of the item. This identifier is automatically generated when a new artwork item is created in the system."
  ref: "https://schema.org/identifier"

- id: "headline"
  type: "semantic"
  text: "Title of the artwork"
  ref: "https://schema.org/headline"

- id: "artform"
  type: "semantic"
  text: "Form of the artwork: painting? photograph? sculpture? others?"
  ref: "https://schema.org/artform"

- id: "authors"
  type: "semantic"
  text: "Authors of this artwork"
  ref: "https://schema.org/author"

- id: "serialNumber"
  type: "semantic"
  text: "Serial number of the artwork. If the artwork does not have a serial number, such as an original painting from an artist, then this number is simply the examplar number, usually 1."
  ref: "https://schema.org/serialNumber"

- id: "description"
  type: "semantic"
  text: "Description of the artwork"
  ref: "https://schema.org/description"

- id: "obtainDate"
  type: "semantic"
  text: "Date on which Alpha Org obtained the ownership of this artwork."
  ref: "https://schema.org/Date"

- id: "itemLocation"
  type: "semantic"
  text: "Location of the storage of the artwork item"
  ref: "https://schema.org/itemLocation"

- id: "images"
  type: "semantic"
  text: "Images of the artwork"
  ref: "https://schema.org/image"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ALPS descriptions don't make distinctions between single items and collections. From the model POV anything could be a collection, from the implementation POV, each service implementing that ALPS description makes their own decisions.

as a common practice, i typically use the IANA link-rel values when it is important

```
rel: item and rel: collection
```

there's a small utility (ALPS UNIFIED) that shows how to convert ALPS descriptions into OpenAPI definitions:
https://github.com/mamund/alps-unified

Comment: Thank you very much Mr. Amundsen! I updated my question and included my current code. Could you please guide me about how to describe the properties "authors" and "images" as arrays in the above code? In Stackoverflow, you can edit your answer to include code snippets.

Comment: you can create a semantic desscriptor called "authors" and then add nested descriptors that _refer_ to the defined properties using descriptors with href attributes.

see this example todo list ALPS document for ideas:
https://github.com/alps-io/profiles/blob/master/yaml/todo-alps.yaml